# Is there any treaty between India and Pakistan that says the Kashmir issue is "bilateral"?

Tags: india, pakistan, kashmir

[USA, Russia, China, Turkey, and UN secretaries-general have all offered mediation on the Kashmir issue over the last 20 years.](https://politics.stackexchange.com/a/76002/32479)

India repeatedly refuses third-party mediation and insists that the Kashmir issue is "bilateral."

- [Kashmir a bilateral issue, India tells US after Trump offers help](https://www.indiatoday.in/india/story/kashmir-a-bilateral-issue-india-tells-us-after-trump-offers-help-1639126-2020-01-22)
- [No role for third parties in Kashmir, India reiterates](https://www.hindustantimes.com/india-news/no-role-for-third-parties-in-kashmir-india-reiterates-101665271604229.html)

Is there any treaty between India and Pakistan that says the Kashmir issue is bilateral?

Comment: The last Hindustan Times article you link to provides the answer: "The Simla Agreement and the Lahore Declaration provide the basis to resolve all issues between India and Pakistan bilaterally". Are you interested in why Pakistan hasn't abandoned these agreements?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Terms like "internal" and "bilateral" are often used rhetorically by countries to avoid risks to their diplomatic position.  Myanmar's Rohingya are an "internal matter" according to itself and China for example.

Given that India is the dominant member of the India-Pakistan duo, and also given that India's position on Kashmir leans against letting the locals decide in a referendum which would probably get international traction, **it is highly predictable that India will try to keep outsiders out - not much to win, plenty to lose.**

As mentioned, there is that [Simla Agreement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simla_Agreement) signed after the [Indo-Pakistani War of 1971](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indo-Pakistani_War_of_1971), which Pakistan had lost (i.e. Pakistan might not have been thrilled at having to sign it):

> The treaty was signed in Simla (also spelt "Shimla") in India by Zulfiqar Ali Bhutto, the President of Pakistan, and Indira Gandhi, the Prime Minister of India.[5] The agreement also paved the way for diplomatic recognition of Bangladesh by Pakistan. Technically, the document was signed at 0040 hours in the night of 3 July; despite this official documents are dated 2 July 1972.[5][6][7] Some of the major outcomes of the Simla Agreement are:
>
> Both countries will "settle their differences by peaceful means through bilateral negotiations".[5][3][8] India has, many a times, maintained that Kashmir dispute is a bilateral issue and must be settled through bilateral negotiations as per Simla Agreement, 1972 and thus, had denied any third party intervention even that of United Nations.[9]

India has what it "wants", Kashmir, and a Indian politician giving up Kashmir would be committing political suicide.  The status quo suits it fine even though solving (i.e. losing) Kashmir would probably benefit Indians as a whole, long term.  This is especially true if a comprehensive peace deal uncoupled Pakistan from its alliance with China which puts pressures on multiple border axis.

As to Pakistan withdrawing from the agreement?  It probably wouldn't get what it wants because negotiations will still only happen according to a format *both* parties have to agree to.  The world is full of disputes where one of the parties wants to involve others at times and doesn't succeed:  Palestine-Israel, South and North Korea come to mind.  Lately Russia is trying to get the West involved in diplomacy but the West is sticking to the script that Ukraine needs to be in the lead in negotiations.

Comment: That I don't know.  But the general motivation for India's insistence on the bilateral nature of the dispute is clear - Kashmir is not something they get much international sympathy about.

Comment: Is it really possible that resolution of Kashmir issue will lead to decoupling of Pak-China axis? There are bigger issues at play there I think, not just Kashmir.